# Is there a way to enable CSV or JSON output formats for MapServer WFS GetPropertyValue requests?

Tags: wfs, mapserver, json, mapfile, getfeature

In a MapServer map file, it is possible to set up a variety of output formats for WFS GetFeature requests.

However, it doesn't seem possible to do the same for a WFS GetPropertyValue request, which only seems to work with these output formats:

```
application/gml+xml; version=3.2
text/xml; subtype=gml/3.2.1
text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1
text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2
```

Is there any way to enable CSV or JSON output for GetPropertyValue requests?

Answer (score 4):

You can setup `OUTPUTFORMAT` declarations which leverage MapServer's use of OGR for custom output formats (including CSV, GeoJSON).  See the [documentation](http://mapserver.org/output/ogr_output.html) for further details.

**Update**: this does not appear to be the case for `GetPropertyValue` requests, only `GetFeature` requests.

Comment: For GetFeature, sure, but does it affect also GetPropertyValue?